# Что такое противопожарная защита?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

Какой смысл несет словосочетание "противопожарная защита"?

Comment: На этот вопрос легко можно найти ответ в Сети.

Comment: Вопрос нужно отредактировать. Здесь речь идет о правильности термина: почему "противопожарная охрана", а не "пожарная охрана". Для сравнения  существуют выражения "защита от радиации" и "радиационная защита". Ответ на этот вопрос найти не так просто, и это лингвистический вопрос

Answer (score 0):

По определению, противопожа́рная защи́та — комплекс мер и технологий, предназначенных **для защиты от пожара**.

[Методы противопожарной защиты | wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B)

Comment: А что, в таком случае, "пожарная защита" и есть ли смысловая разница в этих словосочетаниях?

Comment: У слова "пожарный"   есть  два значения: (1) относящийся к пожару и (2) тот, кто входит в команду, занимающуюся тушением пожаров.  А терминология должна быть точной: защита пожарных (людей) или защита от пожара (противопожарная защита).