# Как правильно: "противопожарная защита" или "пожарная защита"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, терминология

Как правильно писать: "противопожарная защита" или "пожарная защита"?

Comment: См. также: [Не принимаю выражение “противопожарная безопасность”](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439675/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: См. также: [Что такое противопожарная защита?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429726/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: "противопожарная защита". Защита всегда направлена против чего-то (противопожарная, противохимическая, противолодочная и т. п.).

См. [в словарях](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/emergency/2246/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F). Например:

> Противопожарная защита: Меры по предотвращению возникновения и распространения пожара, защиты путей эвакуации и создающие условия для эффективной борьбы с пожаром, в т.ч. регламентацию огнестойкости, пожарной опасности и поведения материалов… …   Словарь-справочник терминов нормативно-технической документации

Там же приведены названия книг, например "Противопожарная защита зданий. Конструктивные и планировочные решения".

См. также на нашем сайте: [Что такое противопожарная защита?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429726/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0)

Не путать с *пожарной безопасностью*:
[Не принимаю выражение "противопожарная безопасность"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439675/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c).

А слова "пожарная защита" должны пониматься как защита, предоставляемая пожарными (как юридическая защита предоставляется юристами), или как защита при помощи пожара.

Сравните: антимагнитня защита — защита от магнитного поля, магнитная защита — защита при помощи магнитного поля.

> Доходя до границы магнитосферы, он не может пробить нашу **магнитную** защиту и уходит в мировое пространство. [Александр Городницкий. Я был как два разных человека – крамольный поэт и благонравный советский инженер (2015)]
>
> Кроме того, часы снабжены **антимагнитной** защитой. Всё это делает прибор настоящим инструментом для человека, любящего скорость. [Аксессуары: Деньги - время (2002) // «Автопилот», 2002.04.15]

Вот еще пример. Минная и противоминная защита.

> Следует добавить, что оборона берега артиллерией обычно сочетается с **минной** защитой, которая не позволяет флоту подойти поближе к батареям для окончательного их уничтожения. [А. К. Коленковский. Дарданелльская операция (1930)]
>
> Академик А.П. Александров в 1937 году возглавил работы по размагничиванию кораблей для их **противоминной** защиты, в 1941-1943 гг. продолжал эти работы в Ленинграде, Севастополе, Сталинграде, Заполярье. [П. Л. Капица. О роли науки в Отечественной войне (1944) // «Наука и жизнь», 1985]

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, правильно так: "противопожарная защита". Что означает безопасность от пожара.

Comment: Зачем сразу ставить минус новому участнику? Ответ, конечно, должен быть аргументированным, но дайте автору время его  дополнить.